# How to change Progressbar status Text in setup project dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I create a Setup for my project in Visual Studio.I want to change the progress bar status Text at runtime.The default status text is "Please Wait" .To change the Status Text I call the API method "MsiGetMode" .But there are two parameter of this method one is "install (Handle to the installation provided to a DLL custom action or obtained through , , or ) " How can i get this first parameter in my installer class.And second parameter is "runmode(Specifies the run mode)" .If there is any other way how can i do that.

Please help me

Thanks & Regards,

Vipin Kumar

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the Visual Studio setup project only provides very basic support for creating installations.  Using the Windows Installer API to control the UI is not a good approach.

I suggest moving to a more robust setup tool such as [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) that will give you more control over your UI.  You could then use wix to customize your setup UI, as explained at [this tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson8.php).